# Insert query based on number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, db2, qsqlquery

I want a query to insert a row into a table I know it is simple but the scenario is the table should not have more than 5 rows. If table has more than five rows I need to remove the old row(Or replace with new row ) (Based on the insert time stamp) then i need to insert a new row.If number of rows less than count 5 then i can directly insert a row.

Please share me the query.

Comment: First the insert and then a row count with a delete or something? Just thinking out loud

Comment: You should show what you have

Comment: Do you really need it to work in all those RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
declare @count int

SELECT @count=COUNT(*)
from EP_ANSWERS

IF (@count<5)
// DO your insert here
ELSE
DELETE FROM TABLE
 WHERE inserttimestamp = (SELECT x.inserttimestamp
                         FROM (SELECT MAX(t.inserttimestamp) AS inserttimestamp
                                 FROM TABLE t) x)
// DO your insert here
```

Comment: If i do not have a inserttimestamp column then how we can identify the  the row which is very old and delete it ?

Comment: It is hard to this answer this without knowing the schema of your table. But if you have an identity column you will be able to get the oldest rows by getting the min id. But if you change ids manually this will not guarantees  the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If it is impossible for the table to have more than 5 rows:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
 WHERE 5 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable)
   AND yourtimestamp = (SELECT MIN(yourtimestamp) FROM yourtable)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable ...
;
```

If it is possible for the table to have more than 5 rows:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
 WHERE 5 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable)
   AND yourtimestamp NOT IN (SELECT yourtimestamp
                               FROM yourtable
                              ORDER BY yourtimestamp DESC
                              LIMIT 4)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable ...
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to put a trigger on the table to maintain this rule, in MySQL the something like this should work

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg__my_table__limit_rows
BEFORE INSERT
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table) = 5)
    BEGIN            
        DELETE FROM my_table
        WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM my_table)  -- change this to fit your logic for which record should be removed
    END
END
```

Comment: `IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table) >= 5)` just a typo i think :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the code here is in pseudo (you didn't wrote your schema), but i wrote where you need to complete your own code.

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRowsToInsert INT = -- select from the data you want to insert
DECLARE @MaxNumberOfRows INT = 5
DECLARE @NumberOfExistingRows INT

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP @rows id FROM SomeTable ORDER BY createdDate ASC'

SELECT @NumberOfExistingRows = COUNT(*)
FROM SomeTable

SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query,'@rows',
 CAST(@NumberOfRowsToInsert - (@MaxNumberOfRows - @NumberOfExistingRows))) AS VARCHAR(1))

CREATE TABLE #IdsToDelete(id INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #IdsToDelete
EXEC(@Query)

DELETE FROM SomeTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM #IdsToDelete)

-- insert here..
```